# Display json data in spreadsheet like looking html table using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need help regarding rendering this JSON data in html table using angular:

```
[{
  "task": "Test1",
  "number": 20,
  "name": "John"
 }, 
 {
  "task": "Test1",
  "number": 10,
  "name": "Doug"
 }, 
 {
  "task": "Test2",
  "number": 50,
  "name": "John"
 }, 
 {
  "task": "Test2",
  "number": 100,
  "name": "Doug"
}]
```

My rendered html table should look like this

```
            Test1      Test2
John        20          50
Doug        10          100
```

Somehow values need to be grouped by, and then rendered, but to keep matching data. Also that first position in array[0][0] should be empty. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it is not a valid JSON format.. check [plz](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Sorry. Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can **group** your data **by name** , and have Object of arrays like following  :

```
{
  "John": [
    {
      "task": "Test1",
      "number": 20,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "task": "Test2",
      "number": 50,
      "name": "John"
    }
  ],
  "Doug": [
    {
      "task": "Test1",
      "number": 10,
      "name": "Doug"
    },
    {
      "task": "Test2",
      "number": 100,
      "name": "Doug"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then , define a function to retrieve data by `name` & `task` : `getItemBy=function(name,task)`

- Those two steps will make your algo easy to render HTML table as u want :

## DEMO :

```js
var data=[{
  "task": "Test1",
  "number": 20,
  "name": "John"
 }, 
 {
  "task": "Test1",
  "number": 10,
  "name": "Doug"
 }, 
 {
  "task": "Test2",
  "number": 50,
  "name": "John"
 }, 
 {
  "task": "Test2",
  "number": 100,
  "name": "Doug"
}];

 var groupBy=function(arr,key) {
      return arr.reduce(function(rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
      }, {});
};
 //------
var groupedByName=groupBy(data,'name');

var getItemBy=function(name,task){
    return groupedByName[name].filter((item)=>item.task===task)
 };

//------


//--
console.log(`***** Item where name=John & task=Test1`,
   getItemBy('John','Test1')
)
console.log(`****** All data after grouping`,
    groupedByName
)
```

Comment: Interesting use of reduce function. I like it. However I still do not understand how should I iterate over the groupedByName object ( it is not an array ) in order to use that data in ng-repeat loop.

Comment: You can loop over object properties by : `Object.keys(groupedByName)`

Comment: see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wftsubbc/) and tell me if useful

Comment: It is useful. Actually similar way to do that in angular is  ng-repeat="(key, value) in groupedByDay". However I am still struggling on how to get the proper html output. I have a feeling that I need to do additional grouping or extracting headers ( in this case Test1, Test2 by maybe creating header collection) to be able to iterate over, and populate this spreadsheet table.

Comment: I was able to implement it using groupByName for left hand columns, and groupByTask for headers. Then I just iterated over the collection with ng-repeat="(key, value) in groupedByName and populated values accordingly. I am not sure how efficient this is, but it works well right now.
Anyway without your help this would not be possible. A big "thanks"